# boost::filesystem::current_path() returns empty path

Tags: c++11, boost, path, boost-filesystem, conan

I have a C++ program where I need the current path to later create a folder. The location of my executable is, let's say `/home/me/foo/bin`. This is what I run:

```
//Here I expect '/home/me/foo/bin/', but get ''
auto currentPath = boost::filesystem::current_path(); 

//Here I expect '/home/me/foo/', but get ''
auto parentPath = currentPath.parent_path();

//Here I expect '/home/me/foo/foo2/', but get 'foo2/'
string subFolder    = "foo2";
string folderPath   = parentPath.string() + "/" + subFolder + "/";

//Here I expect to create '/home/me/foo/foo2/', but get a core dump
boost::filesystem::path boostPath{ folderPath};
boost::filesystem::create_directories( boostPath);
```

I am running on Ubuntu 16.04, using Boost 1.66 installed with the package manager Conan.

I used to run this successfully with a previous version of Boost (1.45 I believe) without using Conan. Boost was just normally installed on my machine. I now get a core dump when running `create_directories( boostPath);`.

Two questions:

1. Why isn't `current_path()` providing me with the actual path, and returns and empty path instead?
2. Even if current_path() returned nothing why would I still have a core dump even if I run it with `sudo`? Wouldn't I simply create the folder(s) at root?

**Edit:**

Running the compiled program, having some `cout` outputs of the above variables in between the lines rather than using debug mode, *normally* gives me the following output:

```
currentPath: ""
parentPath: ""
folderPath: /foo2/
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

But *sometimes* (about 20% of the times) gives me the following output:

```
currentPath: "/"
parentPath: "/home/me/fooA�[oFw�[oFw@"
folderPath: /home/me/fooA�[oFw�[oFw@/foo2/
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'boost::filesystem::filesystem_error'
  what():  boost::filesystem::create_directories: Invalid argument
Aborted (core dumped)
```

**Edit 2:**

Running `conan profile show default` I get:

```
[settings]
os=Linux
os_build=Linux
arch=x86_64
arch_build=x86_64
compiler=gcc
compiler.version=5
compiler.libcxx=libstdc++
build_type=Release
[options]
[build_requires]
[env]
```

Comment: Did you make sure that you don't have any access (permission) issues?

Comment: @A.Gille, I had indeed such concern while debugging with VS Code, and ruled it out using `sudo run` and adding some `cout` in between the lines to print paths on console. The results were the same.

Comment: By `sudo run` do you mean running your compiled executable with `sudo`?
Try directly calling `getcwd()` and check `errno` to see what might go wrong.

Comment: Please make sure regarding the conan package that your ``conan install`` settings are aligned with your build settings. For example, the default profile (.conan/profiles/defaul, or ``conan profile show default``) uses ``libcxx=libstdc++`` for backward compatibility reasons. But your compiler might be using ``libcxx=libstdc++11`` as default. Usually this means link errors, not runtime, but please check just in case.

Comment: @drodri, thanks. I added the output of `conan profile show default` to my question, and it is indeed as you guessed. However, I don't know how to check what my compile uses. Could you suggest me a link to learn how to find it?

Comment: @A.Gille, thanks for the suggestion. I incorporated some temporary lines in the code following the example implementation of [this link](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSLTBW_2.3.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r3.bpxbd00/rtgtc.htm). With this approach, I find the correct path, `home/me/foo/`. I actually expected `home/me/foo/bin/` which is where my compiled code resides, but at least we know I'm in the right place, and that `current_path()` is giving me a totally wrong output.

Comment: @drodri, I was looking at the Github [page of the boost 1.66 for Conan](https://github.com/conan-community/conan-boost/tree/release/1.66.0), and I realised I never setup the profile. Especially missing the `[env]` section looks like a very strong candidate to be my problem. I'll try to set it up correctly.

Comment: @raggot as a quick check, I would just edit the default profile, write ``libstdc++11`` as the default libcxx, and try to ``conan install`` your dependencies again and then re-build your app. Typically g++>5 will use ``libstdc++11`` in modern distros. Older compiler and old distros will use ``libstdc++``.

Comment: `current_path` tells you the *working directory* which is not necessarily the *executable file's location*.

Comment: @drodri, it worked! If you will elaborate it in an answer adding a few explanatory lines I'll be happy to accept it :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is some discrepance between the `libcxx` used in the dependencies, and the one that you are using to build your application.

In g++ (linux) there are 2 standard library modes you can use, `libstdc++`, built without C++11 enabled, and `libstdc++11`, built with C++11 enabled. When you are building an executable (application or shared library), all the individual libraries linked together must link with the same `libcxx`.

- `libstdc++11` was made the default for g++ >= 5, but this also depends on the linux distro. It happens that even if you install a g++ >=5 in older distros like Ubuntu 14, the default `libcxx` will still be `libstdc++`, apparently it is not easy to upgrade it without breaking. It also happens that very popular CI services used in open-source, like travis-ci, used older linux distros, and thus `libstdc++` linkage was the most popular.
- `libstdc++` was the default for g++ < 5.

For historical and backwards compatibility reasons, conan default profile always use `libstdc++`, even for modern compilers in modern distros. You can read your default profile the first time conan is executed, but also find it as a file in `.conan/profiles/default`, or show it with `conan profile show default`. This will likely change in conan 2.0 (or even sooner), and the correct `libcxx` will be detected for each compiler if possible.

So, if you are not changing the default profile (using your own profiles is recommended for production), then when you execute `conan install`, the depedencies which are installed are built against `libstdc++`. Note that this `conan install` is independent on the build in most cases, it just downloads, unzip and configure the dependencies you want, with the requested configuration (from the default profile).

Then, when you are building, if you are not changing [_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI](https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/howtos/manage_gcc_abi.html), then you can be using your system compiler default, in this case, `libstdc++11`. In most cases, a linking error appears that shows this discrepance. But in your case you were unlucky, and your application managed to link, but then crashed at runtime.

There are a couple of approaches to solve this:

- Build your application with `libstdc++` too. Make sure to define `_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0`.
- Install your dependencies for `libstdc++11`. Edit your default profile to use `libstdc++11`, then issue a new `conan install` and rebuild your app.

Comment: Very clear explanation. I now understand more of what is happening in the background and why it wasn't working. Thanks.